# Reduce Confirmations in the block coins to mature

Tags: transactions, litecoin, altcoin

I have created a alternative coin by using the fork of litecoin, and succeeded. But i need to change the Confirmations of first mining transaction

**How can i reduce the Default Confirmation '101' for the coins to mature ? Instead that i need only 50 Confirmation ?**

am working on litecoin master

can anyone help me